# Html.EditorFor Generic List of HttpPostedFileBase

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Is there a way to use Html.EditorFor with a generic list of HttpPostedFileBase objects?

I am building a site where on one of the pages someone can attach up to 3 files. My code currently looks like this -

**Model -**

```
public IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> Attachments { get; set; }
```

**View -**

```
<div>
    @{
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
           <input type="file" name="Attachments[@i]" />
        }
    }
</div>
```

Is there some way to replace `<input type="file" name="Attachments[@i]" />` with a `EditorFor` statement?

Comment: Create an `EditorTemplate`

Answer (score 0):

you can do it like this

```
  <div>
       @{
         for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
              {
                @Html.Editor("Attachments["+ i +"]", new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "file" }})
              }
        }
  </div>
```

or

```
<div>      
          @Html.Editor("Attachments", new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "file" }})
          @Html.Editor("Attachments", new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "file" }})
          @Html.Editor("Attachments", new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "file" }})

</div>
```

you can also use `TextBox`

```
@Html.TextBox("Attachments",new { type = "file" })
```